# Linking List & Label Report Containers with Additional Text

Tags: listlabel

I have two report containers that are linked to each other. At the end of my report (means when the second container has been printed) I need to print a text. Of course I could link the text to the two report containers. But this will not be understandable for my end users. Also, in the Designer this looks very bad. Any ideas how to make this better?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the UI/UX site, but really this could benefit from some screen shots and mockups too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you'd use multiple report containers to display independent information side-by-side. From your description, it sounds like you'd actually would like to print sequential information. If that's the case, I wouldn't use multiple report containers at all but rather stick to just one, which contains multiple tables. The big benefit is you don't have to care about the linking which is wired up automatically for you then. Example:

[image: Object List with Report Container]

The shot shows a report container with two independent tables and a table with static content. You can append more elements as required.

At print time, this will render as (just using some arbitrary fields)

[image: Result in Preview]

which sounds like what you're trying to achieve.